# django queryset sorting by fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm

i have this model:

```py
class ProgrammingQuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    programming_question = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='programming_question_a', null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='writer_answer_programming_question', null=True, blank=True)
    accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    result = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    max_score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
```

I want to write a query for get users who solve more questions(have more accept=True) and those who are equal are sorted by time(time field)
Thanks

Comment: oh, sorry. I removed that

Comment: Your question seem unclear a bit. Please enrich it with an example of given some sample data what would be the result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
accepted = Q( 'writer_answer_programming_question__accept=True')

User.objects.all.annotate(
    accepted_count = Count('writer_answer_programming_question', filter = accepted    
    ).order_by('accepted_count', 'time'
    )
```

Doc:
[Aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions), [Filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

Comment: thanks @nigel222
but I don't want write query on User model. I want get user field on ProgrammingQuestionAnswer model(ForeignKey)